# How do I iterate over files in a directory including sub directories, using Python?

Tags: python, windows, file-io, filesystems

I try writing a script that counts the lines of code in a project.

The problem I have is it doesn't find all files.

The script looks like this:

```
import os

root = r"C:\Users\username\data\projects\test"

allLines = []

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(path, name)

        if not filepath.endswith( ('.cs','.vb') ):
            break

        with open(filepath) as f:
            lines = f.read().splitlines()

            for line in lines:
                allLines.append(line)

print(len(allLines))
```

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the issue is the `break`, if the file doesn't end with .cs or .vb you just skip the directory, you need to change it for `continue` as follows:

```
import os

root = r"C:\Users\frank\Daten\Projekte\CS\mpv.net"

allLines = []

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(path, name)

        if not filepath.endswith( ('.cs','.vb') ):
            continue

        with open(filepath) as f:
            lines = f.read().splitlines()

            for line in lines:
                allLines.append(line)

print(len(allLines))
```

This code can also receive improvements:

```
import os

root = r"C:\Users\frank\Daten\Projekte\CS\mpv.net"

allLines = 0

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):

    for name in files:

        if not filepath.endswith( ('.cs','.vb') ):
            continue

        filepath = os.path.join(path, name)

        with open(filepath) as f:
            lines += len(f.read().splitlines())

print(allLines)
```

Comment: awesome @stax76 check the performance improvements that I just added, no need to re iterate to add to all lines you can sum de len right away, also no need to generate the whole file path if the file doesn't end as you expect